# How to run a crontab job on elastic search docker image

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, cron

I want to run a crontab job on elastic search docker image and here is my docker file

```
FROM docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.6.0

ENV PATH=$PATH:/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin

RUN yum -y update

RUN yum -y install crontabs

RUN echo -e "root\nelasticsearch" > /etc/cron.allow

RUN echo "" >> /etc/cron.allow

RUN chmod -R 644 /etc/cron.d

RUN cat /etc/cron.allow

RUN chown -R elasticsearch /etc/cron.d

RUN chmod -R 755 /etc/cron.d

RUN chown -R elasticsearch /var/spool/cron

RUN chmod -R 744 /var/spool/cron

RUN chown -R elasticsearch /etc/crontab

RUN chmod -R 744 /etc/crontab

RUN chown -R elasticsearch /etc/cron.d

RUN chmod -R 744 /etc/cron.d

COPY ./purge.sh /usr/share/elasticsearch

RUN ls -l /etc/crontab

RUN ls -l /etc/cron.d

RUN touch /usr/share/elasticsearch/cron.log

ADD ./cron /etc/cron.d/cron_test

RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/cron_test

RUN cd /etc/cron.d && cat cron_test

RUN chown -R elasticsearch /etc/cron.d/cron_test

RUN ls -l /etc/cron.d/cron_test

RUN crontab /etc/cron.d/cron_test

RUN crontab -l

RUN cd /var/spool/cron && ls

USER elasticsearch

ENTRYPOINT elasticsearch

CMD crond start && pgrep cron && tail -f && tail -f /usr/share/elasticsearch/cron.log

EXPOSE 9200 9300
```

**after running this docker file and executing the container**, i am getting this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTMuF.png)

In this step in docker file
RUN cd /var/spool/cron && ls

it's showing only root , but how can i get elasticsearch user in it ?**

my cron file present locally

```
*/1 * * * * echo "Hello world" >> /usr/share/elasticsearch/cron.log
*/1 * * * * elasticsearch /usr/share/elasticsearch/purge.sh
```

**my purge.sh file**

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/hydro_dashboard_index/_delete_by_query" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
"query": {
"range" : {
"query_service_entry_time" : {
"lt" : "now-14d"
}
}
}
}'
```

Answer (score 1):

It's usually considered a better practice to run only one process in a container.  Since the thing you're trying to run in cron is just making an HTTP request to elasticsearch, there's nothing about it that needs to run in the same container, or even in Docker at all.

If your host is running a standard Linux distribution with a standard cron daemon, the absolute easiest thing to do is just to stash this `purge` script somewhere on your host and run it via the host's cron service.  If you know cron and elasticsearch are on the same host and you start the container with a `-p 9200:9200` option to publish the standard elasticsearch HTTP port, the script should work unmodified.

If absolutely everything *must* run in Docker, you might [search Docker Hub for a prebuilt cron image](https://hub.docker.com/search?q=cron&type=image) (there are a couple, though none look especially actively maintained).  You also might be able to use the minimal set of tools in the [busybox](https://busybox.net/) [image](https://hub.docker.com/_/busybox/); [its documentation](https://busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html) can be a little light.  Still, the basic approach you'd need to take looks like:

- Find or build a Docker image that contains only `cron` and `curl` – no Elasticsearch, no actual crontabs, just the programs themselves.
- If you're manually `docker run`ning containers, `docker network create some_network` (with any name and default options), and run both the Elasticsearch and cron containers with `--net some_network`.
- In the `curl` commands, use the `docker run --name` of the Elasticsearch container, or the name of its Docker Compose `services:` block, as a hostname; `localhost` will always mean "this container".
- Put the crontabs and support scripts in some directory on your host, and inject them into the cron container with the `docker run -v` option (that is, treat them as configuration).